# How to add difference row to each index value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Index_1 Index_2 Week_1 Week_2 Week_3
 0       A        1      2      3
         B        2      3      4
 1       A        4      5      6
         B        7      8      9
```

For each unique value in Index_1, I want to add a row to Index_2, called "Diff" that will calculate the difference between A and B in Week_1, Week_2, Week_3, and so on.

See below for what I'm hoping it'll look like:

```
Index_1 Index_2 Week_1 Week_2 Week_3
 0       A        1      2      3
         B        2      3      4
         Diff     1      1      1
 1       A        4      5      6
         B        7      8      9
         Diff     3      3      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is `stack/unstack`:

```
new_df = df.unstack(level=-1).stack(level=0)
new_df['Diff'] = new_df['B'] - new_df['A']
new_df = new_df.unstack(level=-1).stack(level=0)
```

Output:

```
                 Week_1  Week_2  Week_3
Index_1 Index_2                        
0       A             1       2       3
        B             2       3       4
        Diff          1       1       1
1       A             4       5       6
        B             7       8       9
        Diff          3       3       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I won't code this out, but my recommendation is to recognize a few things. 
You are displaying multiple values in two arrays that are 5 columns wide and 4 rows tall. (Or one array 7 rows tall), or a 3 dimensional array that stores all the information in a very concise and recognizable manner. It's all about choosing how to normalize data. 
My recommendation is to write your code to **store** the **Subtrahend** and **Minuend** in the array.
Then Write the code to **calculate** the **Difference** and **store** it in the array.
Then write the code to **display** the array in the manner you intend.
Tell the story, pseudocode the story, then code in the pseudocode.

Comment: I think that this would be more appropriate as comment.

Comment: I agree. I think I am going to work on it when I am not at work later. I haven't python'd in a while. (4 years). That being said :) #Tellthestory. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
diff = df.groupby('Index_1').diff().dropna().rename(index={'B': 'Diff'})
df = df.append(diff).sort_index()
```

Result:

```
                 Week_1  Week_2  Week_3
Index_1 Index_2                        
0       A           1.0     2.0     3.0
        B           2.0     3.0     4.0
        Diff        1.0     1.0     1.0
1       A           4.0     5.0     6.0
        B           7.0     8.0     9.0
        Diff        3.0     3.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about with dict:

```
dict = {
    "dataframe":[
        {   
        "A":[1,2,3],
        "B":[2,3,4]
        },
        {   
        "A":[4,5,6],
        "B":[7,8,9]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this code:

```
for i in dict["dataframe"]:
    i["diff"] = []
    for weak in range(len(i["A"])):
        i["diff"].append(i["B"][weak]-i["A"][weak])
```

result:

```
{
    "dataframe":[
        {   
        "A":[1,2,3],
        "B":[2,3,4],
        "diff":[1,1,1],
        },
        {   
        "A":[4,5,6],
        "B":[7,8,9],
        "diff":[3,3,3]
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess this is more readable for newbies like me.